# Connecting README to CocoaPod podspec

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, podspec

I have successfully added a pod to CocoaPods [here](https://cocoapods.org/pods/ActionSwift3), however the text of the readme file doesn't appear in the Pod's homepage. I notice that the Pod is marked down points for having an empty and minimal readme, but as you can see in the [github repo](https://github.com/craiggrummitt/ActionSwift3) a README.md file exists that isn't being displayed for some reason.

I suspect the problem is in the [pod spec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/ActionSwift3/1.43/ActionSwift3.podspec.json), but I can't find a readme attribute(and `readme` is one of those things that is very hard to google!)

The `description` attribute is being parsed ok, so I imagine I could put the text of the readme here, but in looking at other pod specs, they don't seem to do this. Am I missing something? How do people generally connect up the readme file?

Comment: What was the key? I see that the Readme is showing up now.

Comment: Pending an answer to this, I ended up adding the entire readme text in the description attribute.